# Please help find my memory leak

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks

I have a simple Cocoa program to plot data read from a Raspberry Pi based server.  After a few thousand reads, the programs memory usage pushes toward 1 GB.  Each read simply gets a long integer for the time and a float value representing temperature read from a temperature sensor.  I've removed everything that I can think of that might utilize memory and the problem does not change.  Please tell me where my problem are.

```
    //
    //  ABSAppDelegate.m
   //  RPi_socket_test   
   //

   #import "ABSAppDelegate.h"
   #include <sys/socket.h> 
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <netinet/in.h>
   #include <netdb.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <arpa/inet.h>

@implementation ABSAppDelegate

- (void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
// Insert code here to initialize your application
NSView *superview = [[self window] contentView];

NSRect fullPlotFrame = [[self window] frame];
fullPlotFrame.size.height *= 0.75;
fullPlotFrame.size.width *= 0.85;
fullPlotFrame.origin.x = [[self window] frame].size.width*0.1;
fullPlotFrame.origin.y = [[self window] frame].size.height*0.02;

thePlot = [[[RPiViewController alloc] initWithFrame:fullPlotFrame] retain];
[superview addSubview:thePlot];
[thePlot display];

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getTemp) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}

-(void)getTemp{

int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
char recvBuff[1024];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

while(ok){
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        ok = false;
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5001);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.27.220.44", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        NSLog(@"\n inet_pton error occured\n");
    }

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
        ok = false;
    }

    while ( (n = (int)read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
    {
        recvBuff[n] = '\0';
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayTemp:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.18s", recvBuff] waitUntilDone:YES];
    }

    if(n < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"\n Read error \n");
    }
    close(sockfd);
    sleep(1);
    [pool drain];
}

}

-(void)displayTemp:(NSString*)theData{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSPoint pointForConversion = NSPointFromString(theData);
[txtTempC setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f, %0.2f", pointForConversion.x, pointForConversion.y]];

long int dataSize = [thePlot SizeOfData];
if(dataSize < 1024) [txtSizeOfData setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Bytes", (int)dataSize]];
  else if(dataSize < 1024*1024) [txtSizeOfData setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f kBytes", (float)dataSize/1024]];
         else [txtSizeOfData setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f MBytes", (float)dataSize/(1024*1024)]];

[thePlot addDataToPlot:pointForConversion];
[thePlot display];
[[self window] display];

[pool drain];
}

-(IBAction)getTemp:(id)sender{
if(!ok){
    ok = true;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getTemp) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
}

-(IBAction)stopClient:(id)sender{
ok = false;
}

-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj{
if([obj object] == txtMax) [thePlot setMaxRawPlotData:(int)[txtMax integerValue]];
}

@end
```

With view controller

```
    //
   //  RPiViewController.m
   //  RPi_socket_test
   //

  #import "RPiViewController.h"

  @implementation RPiViewController

  - (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
 {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
    fontSize = 10;

    NSMutableDictionary *drawStringAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [drawStringAttributes setValue:[NSColor blackColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    NSFont *myFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:fontSize];
    [drawStringAttributes setValue:myFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    NSString* strLabelWidth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", 55.55];
    float labelWidth = [strLabelWidth sizeWithAttributes:drawStringAttributes].width;

    NSRect frameForData = [self bounds];
    frameForData.origin.x += labelWidth;
    frameForData.size.width -= labelWidth;

    myPlot = [[[RPiView alloc] initWithFrame:frameForData] retain];

    [self addSubview:myPlot];
}

return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
// Drawing code here.

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSPoint minPoint = [myPlot findMinValues];
NSPoint maxPoint = [myPlot findMaxValues];

NSMutableDictionary *drawStringAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[drawStringAttributes setValue:[NSColor blackColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
NSFont *myFont = [NSFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:fontSize];
[drawStringAttributes setValue:myFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSString* MinTempLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", minPoint.y];
NSPoint pointToDrawLabel = {0,0};
[MinTempLabel drawAtPoint:pointToDrawLabel withAttributes:drawStringAttributes];

NSString* MaxTempLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", maxPoint.y];
pointToDrawLabel.y = [self bounds].size.height - [MaxTempLabel sizeWithAttributes:drawStringAttributes].height;
[MaxTempLabel drawAtPoint:pointToDrawLabel withAttributes:drawStringAttributes];

[pool drain];
}

-(void)addDataToPlot:(NSPoint)theDataToPlot{
[myPlot addDataToPlot:theDataToPlot];
}


-(long int)SizeOfData{
long int dataSize = [myPlot SizeOfData];

return dataSize;
}

-(int)setMaxRawPlotData:(int)theMax{
 return [myPlot setMaxRawPlotData:theMax];
 }

 @end
```

And subview controller

```
     //
     //  RPiView.m
     //  RPi_socket_test
     //

     #import "RPiView.h"

     @implementation RPiView

     - (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
     {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
    maxRawPlotData = 3600;
    firstRawPlotIndex = 0;
    dataCount = 0;
}

return self;
}

  - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
  {    // Drawing code here.
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSPoint minPoint = [self findMinValues];
NSPoint maxPoint = [self findMaxValues];

float xScale = ([self bounds].size.width)/(maxPoint.x - minPoint.x);
float yScale = [self bounds].size.height/(maxPoint.y - minPoint.y);

[[NSColor whiteColor] set];
NSRect fillArea = [self bounds];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:fillArea];


NSBezierPath *pathForPlot = [[NSBezierPath alloc] init];
if(dataCount<maxRawPlotData){
    if(dataCount>1){
        NSPoint p1 = myData[0];
        p1.x = (p1.x-minPoint.x)*xScale;
        p1.y = (p1.y-minPoint.y)*yScale;
        [pathForPlot moveToPoint:p1];
    }
    for(int i=1; i<dataCount; i++){
        NSPoint p = myData[i];
        p.x = (p.x-minPoint.x)*xScale;
        p.y = (p.y-minPoint.y)*yScale;
        [pathForPlot lineToPoint:p];
    }
}
else{
    unsigned long firstPointToPlot = dataCount-maxRawPlotData;
    NSPoint p1 = myData[firstPointToPlot];
    xScale = [self bounds].size.width/maxRawPlotData;
    minPoint.x = p1.x;
    p1.x = (p1.x-minPoint.x)*xScale;
    p1.y = (p1.y-minPoint.y)*yScale;
    [pathForPlot moveToPoint:p1];
    for(unsigned long i=firstPointToPlot; i<dataCount; i++){
        NSPoint p = myData[i];
        p.x = (p.x-minPoint.x)*xScale;
        p.y = (p.y-minPoint.y)*yScale;
        [pathForPlot lineToPoint:p];
    }
}
[[NSColor blackColor] set];
[pathForPlot stroke];

[pool drain];
}

-(void)addDataToPlot:(NSPoint)theDataToPlot{
myData[dataCount] = theDataToPlot;
dataCount++;
 }

-(NSPoint)findMaxValues{
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSPoint maxValue = {-1e9, -1e9};

for(int i=0; i<dataCount; i++){
    NSPoint testValue = myData[i];
    if(testValue.x > maxValue.x) maxValue.x = testValue.x;
    if(testValue.y > maxValue.y) maxValue.y = testValue.y;
}
[pool drain];
return maxValue;
}

-(NSPoint)findMinValues{
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSPoint maxValue = {1e9, 1e9};

for(int i=0; i<dataCount; i++){
    NSPoint testValue = myData[i];
    if(testValue.x < maxValue.x) maxValue.x = testValue.x;
    if(testValue.y < maxValue.y) maxValue.y = testValue.y;
}
[pool drain];
return maxValue;
}

-(long int)SizeOfData{
long int dataSize = 0;
for(int i=0; i<dataCount; i++){
    dataSize += sizeof(NSPoint);
}

return dataSize;
}

-(int)setMaxRawPlotData:(int)theMax{
if(theMax<10) theMax = 10;
maxRawPlotData = theMax;
return (int)dataCount;
}

@end
```

Comment: You want us to look through all *that*?

Comment: Peter, IF the crash is related to release or retain object, then i would like to say please enable zombie in your xcode setting (Inside Left top Edit Scheme inside that you will get option). Once you enable the same it will be helpful to you analyze the crash

Comment: There is no crash.  It just eats ever more memory.  I think it must be in the client loop.  I am new to network programming and fear that I may have some leak that I would never discover with my knowledge base.

Comment: @SergePashkevich, I am not a professional programmer.  I have seen people berated for not posted sufficient code, so I just put the entirety of my code up.  Just hoping for someone with professional knowledge base to see an obvious error.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you find when you run this code under Instruments with the Leaks template?

Comment: Be sure to also try running Analyze under the Product menu. It will search for some types of memory errors and other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after painfully turning off code section by section, I tracked the leak to the drawRect method in the subview controller.  By adding NSAutoreleasePools everywhere I could and releasing the NSBezierPath, the leak was plugged.

Thanks for giving me an outlet to "think out loud" about this!

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
 {    // Drawing code here.
 NSAutoreleasePool* uberpool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSPoint minPoint = [self findMinValues];
NSPoint maxPoint = [self findMaxValues];

float xScale = ([self bounds].size.width)/(maxPoint.x - minPoint.x);
float yScale = [self bounds].size.height/(maxPoint.y - minPoint.y);

[[NSColor whiteColor] set];
NSRect fillArea = [self bounds];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:fillArea];

NSBezierPath *pathForPlot = [[NSBezierPath alloc] init];
if(dataCount<maxRawPlotData){
    if(dataCount>1){
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSPoint p1 = myData[0];
        p1.x = (p1.x-minPoint.x)*xScale;
        p1.y = (p1.y-minPoint.y)*yScale;
        [pathForPlot moveToPoint:p1];

        [pool drain];
    }
    for(int i=1; i<dataCount; i++){
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSPoint p = myData[i];
        p.x = (p.x-minPoint.x)*xScale;
        p.y = (p.y-minPoint.y)*yScale;
        [pathForPlot lineToPoint:p];

        [pool drain];
    }
}
else{
    unsigned long firstPointToPlot = dataCount-maxRawPlotData;
    NSPoint p1 = myData[firstPointToPlot];
    xScale = [self bounds].size.width/maxRawPlotData;
    minPoint.x = p1.x;
    p1.x = (p1.x-minPoint.x)*xScale;
    p1.y = (p1.y-minPoint.y)*yScale;
    [pathForPlot moveToPoint:p1];
    for(unsigned long i=firstPointToPlot; i<dataCount; i++){
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        NSPoint p = myData[i];
        p.x = (p.x-minPoint.x)*xScale;
        p.y = (p.y-minPoint.y)*yScale;
        [pathForPlot lineToPoint:p];

        [pool drain];
    }
}
[[NSColor blackColor] set];
[pathForPlot stroke];

[pathForPlot release];
[uberpool drain];
}
```

Comment: Using Instruments and watching the NSBezierPaths pile up would have found it a lot less painfully.

Comment: I am not familiar with this.  I will do some research on it.  Thank you!